# Delphi Split(): retrieve the separator into separators list

Tags: delphi

i want retrieve (at runtime) the separator that split a string, eg.:

```
aStr := 'foo=bar';
aParts := aStr.Split(['=', '!', '<', '>', '^']);
```

`aParts[0]` is `foo`, `aParts[1]` is `bar`, but who is the separator? there is any way for retrieve the char used for split the string: `=`?

Comment: Maybe `aStr[Length(aParts[0])+1]`?

Comment: @TomBrunberg i'm stupid, sorry :D

Comment: Or, you just didn't see it that way. But please add some checking for split actually happened to prevent errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to parse the delimiters separately. For instance, the following code will put your delimiters into a second array named separators.

```
var
  astr: string;
  aparts: System.TArray<System.string>;
  separators: System.TArray<System.string>;
  findindex: integer;
  findpos: integer;
begin
  astr := 'foo=bar!abc^def';
  aparts := astr.Split(['=', '!', '<', '>', '^']);
  findindex := 1;
  repeat
    findpos := astr.IndexOfAny(['=', '!', '<', '>', '^'], findindex);
    if findpos >= 1 then
    begin
      SetLength(separators, length(separators) + 1);
      separators[length(separators) - 1] := astr.Substring(findpos, 1);
    end;
    findindex := findpos + 1;
  until findpos = -1;
end;
```